# How to keep cooked French fries (for French fry dogs) warm and crispy?

Tags: storage-method, french-fries

I want to make French fry dogs. Basically, hot dogs that are battered and then coated with cooked French fries and then deep fried.

I have tried cooking them and then setting them aside for a couple of minutes, but they turn out to be cold and the crispness was gone.

[image]

Comment: What is "French fries coat in a hot dog with batter"? How are you cooking it? Why are you trying to store it? Please add details to your question.

Comment: You can add a link to a picture

Comment: A lot of batters, especially based on potatoes, will change color due to oxidation after a short time, but it's entirely harmless.

Comment: Do you mean a [corndog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corn_dog)? Please [edit] so we understand what you're making :)

Comment: Pretty sure he's referring to a battered hot dog which is coated with french fries and deep fried. It's a Korean street food.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what kind of fries you are using. If they're frozen fries— who knows. They're not all processed the same way— some have flour or batter coatings— aren't all made from the same material— some are made from formed, pureed potato and/or reconstituted potato flour— or cooked to the same level of doneness. If they're fresh potatoes which have been par cooked, they'll last in the refrigerator at least overnight before they dry out.

The other problem is your batter. If you're using a batter with baking powder, carbonation, or anything else like that to give it a little puff, it will flatten out if you hold it for more than a few minutes.

Generally, foods with batters are much better when you cook them immediately. If you only need to store it for a short amount of time, maybe less than half an hour, cook it then put it in an oven preheated to the lowest possible temperature (ideally there's a warming setting) on a sheet pan with a wire rack on it. It should keep the fries crispy, but the longer you keep it in there, the drier it will get.

Good luck!